# Unity virtual method with return

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to have my virtual update method set up so it can return in case the mouse is over a UI object.

The thing is, if it returns, the method that override it and uses "base.Update()" still keeps running, as the override also override the original return.

This is the rough code:

**Level.cs** *(for example)*

```
protected virtual void Update () {
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        return;
}
```

**Level1.cs** *(for example)*

```
protected override void Update () {
    base.Update();

    // Code that I don't want to run in case the original method returned
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding is not the right tool for this job. Returning from a base method, just like returning from any method, only passes control back to the method that called it (in this case, resuming your child class's Update).

To tell the calling method not to proceed, you need to send it an explicit signal, something like this:

```
public class BaseBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    protected bool ShouldContinueAfterSharedUpdate() {
        // Put logic you always want to execute here.

        if(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            return false; // "No, don't continue."

        // Put logic that should execute only conditionally here.
        // ...

        return true; // "Yes, continue with subclass-specific updates."
    }
}


public class DerivedBehaviour : BaseBehaviour {

    void Update() {
        // Run shared update logic and detect if we should abort.
        if(ShouldContinueAfterSharedUpdate() == false)
            return; // We got an abort signal, so we're done.

        // Put logic that should execute only conditionally here.
        // ...
    }
}
```

In general, be a bit wary about relying too heavily on inheritance in Unity. Because of its component-based structure, you often get better code flexibility (and fewer serialization woes) from going with the flow of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). If all you need is a common way to early-out of updates, a static utility method works just as well, and can be called from any class regardless of its relationship in the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've thought about using some flag to do this - the thing is, because I'm going to have many levels (10's or 100's) I don't want to write this check in every level's Update and then in case I need to change it, I'll have to change it in every level.

Comment: How is this different from calling `base.Update()` in every one of those cases? It's just another boilerplate one-liner if that's what you want to do. It sounds though like the root of this problem is that you're trying to do hundreds of similar things with hundreds of individual scripts. It's very likely there are ways you can architect this in a data-driven way to avoid such a code explosion and the corresponding maintenance headaches you describe. Try asking a question describing this problem and users may be able to suggest more efficient solutions.